# send data in arraylist to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, javafx

I want to send the the data in my arraylist in java to an array in js.  I searched on the web but I am still not sure how to do it.  I saw someone tried to do it by writing the js and javacode together.  How can I do it separately?  In other words, java code and js code are separate.  Please the picture below. 
I want to use javaFx or something that does **not** need to go through the internet like jsp.
Thank you so much.

[js and java code are seperate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBzAL.png)

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;


public class SendData extends Application{
    Button send;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView myWebView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = myWebView.getEngine();
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("string1");
        arr.add("string2");
        arr.add("string3");
        arr.add("string4");
        arr.add("string5");


        send = new Button("send_to_js");
        send.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                /*?*/
            }

        });
        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.getChildren().addAll(myWebView, send);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vb, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
}




$(document).ready(function() {
    /* how do I put the data into the array*/
    var receiver = [...];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, `Java` and `Javascript` are 2 different languages and thus it is not possible for you to directly pass the Java data structures around freely between both worlds.

The usual approach for solving such a problem is through serialization. That is, you would encapsulate your data from the `java` world into some data format e.g. XML or JSON and then from your `javascript` process, parse the serialized data into `Javascript` object.

For instance let say you have a simple Java class call Car with properties "color" and "Brand" and you have an array of Car.

```
Car[] cars = new Car[3];
```

You could represent this in JSON as;

```
{
    cars: [
        0: { brand: "Honda", color: "Red" },
        1: { brand: "BMW", color: "Black" },
        2: { brand: "Toyota", color: "Yellow" }
    ]
}
```

Then with this JSON document, you could then parse it into a javascript array with objects.

As for how you can pass a JSON document around from 1 process to another or even from macihne to machine, there are any ways you could do it.

You can either serialize the JSON data as a flat file and then read the content from another side or typically people just make use of the web service technology.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know little-to-nothing about JavaFX, but could you use [`WebEngine.executeScript`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-)?

```
// JSON-ify the ArrayList
String json = "[";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    if (i != 0) json += ",";
    json += "'"+arr[i]+"'"; // NOTE: this doesn't escape special characters in arr[i]
}
json += "]";

// pass it to some JS function?
engine.executeScript("someFunction("+json+")");
```